# Is "at DOING something" classified as nominalization?

Tags: nominalizations

In this sentence,

> Attempts by economists at defining full employment have been met with failure.

Is "defining" classified as a form of nominalization?

Comment: No: there is nothing noun-like about "defining" in your example other than the fact that it is complement of the preposition "at". "Defining full employment ..." is just a gerund-participial clause which, incidentally, could be replaced by the infinitival clause "to define full employment".

Comment: Right. If it has an object, it's a verb, not a noun. If it has an article, it's a noun, not a verb. This one has an object.

Answer (score 1):

From the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language: *As a word-formation process, nominalisation prototypically involves the formation of a noun from bases of other classes, by affixation, conversion, or phonological modification*.

If it is 'defining' that has been nominalized, the phrase it heads should be able to take the range of dependents characteristic of a noun phrase.

> *Attempts by economists at **the** defining full employment have been met with failure. (determiner)
>
> *Attempts by economists at **good** defining full employment have been met with failure. (adjective as pre-head modifier)

It plainly cannot, and hence there is no nominalization.

A clear sign of nominalization of verbs is the presence of what would have been a direct object in the clause headed by the verb appearing as an oblique complement in the corresponding NP in a PP headed by *of*.

> Attempts by economists at **the** defining **of** full employment have
> been met with failure.

The above would be an example of nominalization, if one accepts the sentence as grammatical. It does produce 26 hits in the Corpus of Contemporary American English, more than half in academic journals.

> Only at the city level are all necessary preconditions present that
> allow **the** **defining** **of** the range of support instruments to be applied
> and their implementation. (ACAD: Geographical Review ; 2019)

Comment: Thank you. The book "Style: Lessons in Clarity and Grace" identifies "defining" as a nominalization. I was quite confused.

Comment: I'd consider 'Attempts by economists at rigorously/fully/... defining full employment' are acceptable, at least hinting strongly at verb character.